# HR made me feel uncomfortable about negotiating salary

Tags: salary, career-development, job-offer, negotiation, human-resources

HR felt like a bully after asking for more compensation by saying "Others that have applied would take this job for a way lesser salary than what you are asking"
and made the situation uncomfortable via a telephone call. My question is how do you come back from a difficult situation when you are being knocked off and get back into the "salary negotiation" part of it?

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: I see no question here, voting to close.

Comment: If they did not counter with a number then you are knocked off.

Comment: Well, you weren't prepared. "Others would take this job for a way lesser salary than what you are asking" (HR has problems with their grammar). Reply: "Sure. But if you want a job well done, you have to pay for it. " On the other hand, with the attitude that HR has shown to you, I'd look elsewhere. So the reply would be "Is that how you run your business? I'm sure there's someone who would do _your_ job for much less. "

Answer (score 3):

That's how negotiation works. You hopefully gave excellent reasons why you were worth the additional money and why it wasn't out of line for that job in that industry; they told you that they would rather risk losing you than pay you more (which they are entitled to do if your arguments weren't convincing enough).

Now  the ball is in your court again. Either ask them what they would need to see from you to justify a raise, or start looking for a good job that pays better, or take what you've got and try again at a later date.

We can't tell you which of those would be best. And we can't give you any magic that will change their minds if you've already made your best case.

Comment: Sometimes when HR/recruiting does things like that, it is reflective of a culture that will do that with everyone and everything.  If you want the job, then go after it, if you are on the fence, keep looking.

Comment: Unfortunately the operative work is "sometimes", @mikep. Sometimes it just means the applicant has an exaggerated idea of his value. Sometimes it means the company has budgeted a specific amount for this position at this time. Sometimes...

Comment: If it's a budget problem, they should say "sorry, but we can only pay $X for this position". Not "others will do it for a lot less".

Comment: @gnasher: Again, operative word is "should". HR isn't necessarily much better at this than the average clueless newbie. Important point I'd that they said "there:s our offer, take it or leave it"  and the OP needs to make a decision. Or so I see it, but I haven't had to negotiate salary in years  and didn't even try when I was first hired, so this is based on decades in the working world rather than specific HR expertise.